# My Hotkey to start something, wont work... someone have any idea?

Tags: c#, function, if-statement, while-loop

I want to set a **Hotkey** for ***Start*** and ***Stop*** my function.
But it seems to not working for me.

I *set* the Key: **X** as *Hotkey*.

*Someone* has any idea what is **wrong** with this *code*?

**Thanks :)**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AutoItX3Lib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;    

// DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

       const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
        

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
            {
                RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.X);
                frmTimer form = new frmTimer();
                form.Show();
                timer1.Start();

            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**i found the Answer to my Question. Hope it can help others :)**

```
    // DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
   
    
    const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1; //HotKey 1
    const int MYACTION2_HOTKEY_ID = 2; //HotKey 2

    public ChaosBot()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.X);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION2_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.Y);
    }
    
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID) //Hotkey 1
        {
            frmTimer form = new frmTimer();
            form.Show();
            timer1.Start();

        }
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION2_HOTKEY_ID) //Hotkey 2
        {
            this.Close();

        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: So what was actually wrong with your code?

Comment: I mistyped exactly one line of code. I had this code from another post here and there it was explained very poorly for beginners, individual lines of code were shown to be used and so I started trying out all the variations. I'm a complete beginner and it was very difficult for me to understand why this line belongs there.

Comment: I forgot to put the code for the hotkey command in my form. instead, I put them directly into an if statement, assuming it was part of a query. I thought: If i press this key then.... and that's where the code belongs. But a lot of people in other posts and forums had reproduced the same error and hope that it will help some to finally see a complete and ready-to-use code without breaking it into individual parts first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).